# Json obj is not acting correct way in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, forms

I am trying to get form data to json object and modify it... But it is not working...

Here is my code-

```
let formData = new FormData(thisForm).entries();

let body = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData));
console.log(body);
console.log(body.firstName);
console.log("service=" + body.service);
body.service = "hello";
```

the console.log(body) is printing output like this-

```
{"prospectType":"1","firstName":"Arnab","middleName":"","lastName":"Maiti","mobileNumber":"07xxxxxx","workPhoneNumber":"","sourceOther":"","streetArea":"Kanakpur","service":"OTT"}
```

But **console.log(body.firstName);** is printing undefined.
Same thing is happening for other things.. What is the problem?

Comment: JSON.stringify converts the object to a string. So you don't have an object with attributes anymore.

Comment: JSON is a textual data interchange format. In JS it's a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `body` is a string, not a JSON object, because you've `JSON.stringify`'d it.

Use `JSON.parse` instead to create a JSON object that you can edit like that.

```js
var body = '{"prospectType":"1","firstName":"Arnab","middleName":"","lastName":"Maiti","mobileNumber":"07xxxxxx","workPhoneNumber":"","sourceOther":"","streetArea":"Kanakpur","service":"OTT"}';

var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(jsonBody.firstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `JSON.stringify()` on the object first.
You use that to transfer the object over http. Apply that later on and you're fine.